# What is the best place to find fairies in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In Tears of the Kingdom, fairies are essential items that revive you when you run out of health. However, the Animal_Insect_F is not easy to find, as they only spawn in specific locations and only when you have *less* than 3 fairies in your inventory. According to [this object map](https://objmap-totk.zeldamods.org/#/map/z2,8,4.84662000449498), there is exactly 1 place where 5 fairies can spawn: Tuft Mountain, to the west of Lurelin Village.
[image]

[image]

Are there any other locations where 5 fairies can spawn, or is Tuft Mountain the best fairy-hunting spot in the game?

Comment: 5 at a time looks like the biggest one to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this spot is useful if you don't have any fairies in your inventory,
because you can get the maximum of 5 from one spot.

However it is far away from a teleporter.

Also, fairies only respawn after a bloodmoon.

Comment: Isn't it best to go there with 2 fairies?

Comment: If you go there with 2 fairies, then only 3 will spawn.

Comment: Have you seen this yourself? Because I've seen several other sources that disagree with you.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as in botw, although there used to be a trick, by holding fairies in your hands more fairies would spawn because they would not count as being in your inventory.